# How to input text between two strings?

Tags: python

When I have this code

```
input('Write your name: ')
```

You can write your name after that string.

```
>>>Write your name: My name
```

But, how to have something display at the end of the input?

```
>>>Write your name: (Name)
>>>Write your name: (Name Name)
>>>Write your name: (Name Name Name)
```

So no matter what you write, the ')' character appears as you are writing?

Comment: just curious, why do you want that functionality?

Comment: You need to write a specialized equivalent of `input` using the input and output streams. It will probably involve `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout`.

Comment: Or you can mess around with https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html

Comment: @Prith I am just curious how would I do such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following implementation, which uses `msvcrt` to read a single char every time and act upon it (treating `Enter` and `Backspace` if encountered):

```
import msvcrt

def input_between_strings (s, t):
    res = ''
    while True:
        print(s, res, t, sep = '', end = ' \r')
        curr = msvcrt.getch()[0]
        if curr == 13:
            print()
            return res
        elif curr == 8:
            res = res[:-1]
        else:
            res += chr(curr)
```

With your case, you can call it like

```
result = input_between_strings('>>> Write your name: (', ')')
```

Comment: `msvcrt` module is only available on Windows.

Comment: @zwer Whatever the solution ends up being here, it's going to be terminal specific.  The above works basically for a dos/command window.  Linux and Mac would have a similar solution but with a different library (curses).

Answer (score -1):

In general you don't get to do that.
The problem is that the user commits the input to your program by hitting `Enter`, which adds a newline to the display.  If you have vertical spacing control on the display, you could back up a line, move to the end, and continue with your output.  Otherwise, you're going to be out of luck ... or worse, you'll have to write your own handlers for `stdin` and `stdout`.